# FHIR publish tool

Tags: hl7-fhir

I use FHIR publish tool to create profile documentation. I organize my extensions in one profile, and extended resources (resources which use extensions) in separate application profiles. Extensions in a resource then have value like 'profileIdofextension#extensionName' in Profile column. But this does not make the extensions to be hyperlinked to the extension where they are defined (the profile containing all extensions). In order to make hyperlink work, I have to put 'prfoileOfExtensionHtmlFileName#extensionName' in the Profile column. Why does not the tool resolve profileId to profileHtmlFileName? In profile xml definition, I think I should refer to profileId but not the html file name.

Answer (score 0):

The way the tool handles profiles was thrown together to prove something, and was never intended to be more. I'm going to rewrite that part in the next couple of months, and all of that will get overhauled completely. I'll announce on my blog (http://healthintersections.com.au) when it's done.

Comment: Thanks Grahame for your answers. BTW, what's the best way to provide tool specific feedback incl. bugs? Is it good to send an email to you?

Comment: Yes, or make a gForge task using the FHIR change tracking system

Comment: If you want to access the FHIR change tracking system, please go to http://gforge.hl7.org/gf/project/fhir/tracker/